# backtrace - hide standard library and boost calls

Tags: c++, debugging, gdb

I am looking at a backtrace in gdb, and it looks really cluttered because of all the calls made into the standard library and boost. Eg. I see `boost::bind` and `std::allocator` on the call stack, and several other similar calls into the standard library or Boost.

I think I would find it helpful to have backtrace show me just the functions explicitly defined in my program. Better yet, it would help further if I could quickly configure the backtrace command to show or hide `std` and `boost` calls as and when I need them.

Any idea how to hide `boost` from the call stack altogether or to configure backtrace to turn boost logging on and off?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no built-in way to do this.

It can be done, though, by writing a Python "frame filter" that drops the frames that you don't care to see.  This isn't particularly hard to do, but it requires writing a bit of Python code using the gdb Python API.

Comment: Here's a frame filter that colorizes the output.  The important bit is https://github.com/tromey/gdb-helpers/blob/master/gdbhelpers/colorize.py#L116 - this is the class that implements the frame filter.  Yours could just drop frames you don't care about.